# bld.inf not found error in carbide.c++ using qt

Tags: qt, symbian

I am trying to build a Qt GUI Main Window project and get the following errors:

- BLDMAKEERROR:Can't find "\Symbian....\BLD.INF
- bldmake returned with exit value=1

In the last two days, I've re-installed above apps many times following all

installation guides; setting up the environment variables but nothing worked

out.

Kindly anyone help as I've been able to build even the Helloworld program.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bld.inf` gets generated by `qmake` from your .pro file. Have you run qmake on your project? In Carbide.C++ Qt perspective it's Project->Run qmake.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem even w/o Qt and qmake. :( The problem is in the IDE: it generates wrong bld.inf! If you open folder "group", which contains bld.inf, you'll see the Icons_aif_scalable_dc.mk file, but in bld.inf it configured as

`PRJ_MMPFILES
    gnumakefile icons_scalable_dc.mk`

And this is the source of the problem, so after changing icons_scalable_dc.mk on Icons_aif_scalable_dc.mk project will be built as it should.